# Cannot boot into homescreen after installed Android PIE

Tags: 9.0-pie, power-options

My phone model is Asus Zenfone Max Z010D. My power button and volume up button are not working. Is there anyway to boot to the homescreen?

Since I have installed Android pie (AEX custom rom), they have this EDL issue (cannot reboot to device/recovery). I accidently rebooted the device, and it went to EDL. Then I rebooted it by holding the volume down key with the phone connected to computer by usb, but it then went off automatically. Now it is only showing the offline charging, while connected to charger.

How to resolve this?

Comment: I belive it wouldn't be possible to boot the phone without atleast the 2 volume buttons. But there is a long way, you can flash it's firmware while it's off and then it will boot itself. On the other side, your phone will be reformatted.

Comment: @TerribleDog Thats not a problem tell me how to flash its firmware??

Comment: you can find it in google based on your phone

Comment: https://firmwarefile.com/asus-zenfone-max-z010d